# How to do a sum with variable (dynamic) range?

Tags: excel, sum, offset

I have a range B3:Bn with dates and a range C2:Y2 with another dates range. I am trying to find a date from a range B3:Bn in a range C2:Y2 and then starting from this cell to sum values. To do this i use:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(C3;0;MATCH(B3;$C$2:$Y$2;0)):Y3)
```

But instead of Y3 I would like to say: Sum values just starting from offset cell value till + 7 other columns.
[image]

Maybe someone can help with it?
Thanks!

Comment: Ale, did you find anything posted here useful? It is useful if you post feedback.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the INDIRECT function. It allows you dynamically create a cell range in a formula. So you could have one cell with a forumla that create your cell range as text e.g.

```
=B1&":"&B2 // in Cell C1, assuming B1 is "A1" and B2 is "A2" this would result in "A1:A2"
```

And then you can dynamically create a cell range from that using Indirect which you can then use function SUM on.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(C1)) // would result the SUM(A1:A2) in our example
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i am not sure that i understood you. 
With Match i can gen starting column number X; with address and indirect function i can get stop point column Y; row is already known, because its always just 1 row. But i dont find a solution in order to do a sum instead of till Y3: from column X till column Y

Answer (score 3):

In the table of the figure, cell B6 contains

```
=SUM(INDEX(A2:P2,1,B4):INDEX(A2:P2,1,B4+B5-1))
```

You may use an adapted formula to carry out your task.
It indirectly sets (with `INDEX`) the initial and final cells for carrying out the sum. I defined it as a starting cell (column 3 of range A2:P2) and a number of cells (4).

Points to consider:

1. You may need to use absolute referencing for some column/row references.
2. You may define your range to sum in slightly different ways.

[image]